# Space between elements

Tags: dojo, dialog

Here I'm creating dialog widget which contains form. This form is being created dynamically   as user triggers any action (Which is working fine). Based on user action, number of `textboxes` are created with button. Below is the code.

```
function myPractice(){


            var paramCount = 3; // as of now, 3 textboxes are being created

            for(i=0; i<paramCount; i++)
            {
              form.domNode.appendChild(dojo.doc.createTextNode("Parameter " + (i+1)));

                new TextBox({
                value: paramList[i]
                }).placeAt(form.containerNode);

            }

            new Button({
                label: "OK",
                onClick: function(){
            }
            }).placeAt(form.containerNode);
        }
```

Everything is working fine. But here issue is, Button is being created at the end of last `textbox`. I want it properly placed in a sequence, at the end of `dialog` widget.[image: Have a look at below image]

How can I place it there at the end of Dialog?

Answer (score 1):

you can make things work as you want and pretty and looks like a real dialog by you using the `dijitDialogPaneActionBar` class [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QWEzC/138/) is a programmatic example of how to create this div pragmatically.

in your code for this to work you should do something like this:

```
function myPractice(){


            var paramCount = 3; // as of now, 3 textboxes are being created

            for(i=0; i<paramCount; i++)
            {
              form.domNode.appendChild(dojo.doc.createTextNode("Parameter " + (i+1)));

                new TextBox({
                value: paramList[i]
                }).placeAt(form.containerNode);

            }



          var actionBar = dojo.create("div", {
              "class": "dijitDialogPaneActionBar"
           }, dlg.containerNode);//dlg should be your dialog 

            new Button({
                label: "OK",
                onClick: function(){
            }
            }).placeAt(actionBar);
        }
```